# jQuery UI tabs: how to send ajax request with post data?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

From [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html("Couldn't load this tab.");
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>


<div class="demo">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo.</p>
</div>
```

How to send **ajax request with post data** in this case (maybe through ajaxOptions).

I do not know how to modify tabs urls to send post data, for example:

```
<li><a href="ajax/content1.html(country:1,city:35)">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="ajax/content2.html(code:'aa')">Tab 1</a></li>
```

Thanks!

**EDITED**:

In jQuery it's:

```
$.load("some_url",{country: countryValue});
```

So I have post header (country) and post value (countryValue).
How to do the same with each tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the AJAX method POST, you can add a `type` to the `ajaxOptions` object. To collect data for the post, you could take advantage of `jQuery.data()` and then hide the POST parameters in the anchor.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content2.html" data-country="1" data-city="35">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo.</p>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var postData = {};

$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        postData = {
            country: parseInt($(ui.tab).data('country')),
            city: parseInt($(ui.tab).data('city'));
        };
    },
    ajaxOptions: {
        type: 'POST',
        data: postData,
        error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
            $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " + "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
        }
    }
});
```

Try it: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d8HKG/1/)

If your parameters change for each link, you'll have to come up with a way to know which parameters you're looking for. You could get the index of the tab in the `select()` event using `ui.index` and use a `switch` to get different parameters for each case. Admittedly this solution isn't very pretty, but it could work.

Comment: Ok, but how to insert specified post data to specified tab (as in my example)

Comment: @VitaliPonomar: See my update. The solution isn't very "pretty" but you might be able to tweak it until it works for you.

Comment: Are you sure with post headers: in a.href you write `data-country`, but in postData you write `country`? But thanks anyway - I will try it in my code.

Comment: @VitaliPonomar: Yes, it works. `data-` is automatically prepended; it's a prefix used by the `jQuery.data()` functionality.

Comment: I've tried this, but ajax content didn't load. When I checked problems I saw such error: `Key 'country' not found in query dictionary` (server technology - Django, Python). SO looks like post data did not send...

Comment: @VitaliPonomar: If you're looking in the query dictionary, then are you sure you want to be POSTing? Maybe you should just use a regular GET (which would put the data on the query string: `page.php?country=1&city=35`).

Comment: I'm using Django, as I said and there get parametrs in urls writes like: /ajax/page/?country=countryValue. But with get method it works fine!!!  THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: In my case, POST method in MVC controller is ignored and tab keeps accessing GET method, which has the same name (but different parameters). Have no idea why. Seems I will need to use preventdefault and make ajax call manually... [This "hack"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657120/how-to-force-ajax-using-post-not-get-and-display-the-response-in-jquery-tabs) helped.