# Passing variable via ajax with Jquery Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I am having a problem that I've been stuck on for days, and I just cant seem to figure it out. 
I'm trying to pass a variable through AJAX using Jquery Tabs.

Here is my use scenario: User loads page with JQuery tabs, default just being some text. On the page, I have a session variable containing there userid. When they click the 2nd tab, it passes that userid variable to the script. I can't get it to pass!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" />
<script>
var postData = {};
$("#tabs").tabs({
select: function(event, ui) {
    postData = {
        userid: parseInt($(ui.tab).data('userid'));
    };
},
ajaxOptions: {
    type: 'POST',
    data: postData,
    error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
        $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " + "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
    }
}
});
</script>

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Intro</a></li>
    <li><a href="Custom/div_charts_test2.html" data-userid="1234">Department</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Text information goes here</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: LOL, actually, your code looks like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301193/jquery-ui-tabs-how-to-send-ajax-request-with-post-data ... Is this not working for you? Have you checked the request in the Network tab of Developer Tools to see if its being made and what response your getting?

Comment: yeah, i saw that posting, and it didn't seem to help! when checking the network tab, i see the post being made, its just blank

Comment: Are you running it on a server? If its running on file:// then it won't "post" and you'll get an error. But you should have seen the error in chromes network tab
http://skitch.shanimal.com/Developer_Tools_-_file__Users_Apple_Desktop_tmp.html%23tabs-1-20121001-060033.png

Answer (score 0):

I tried a test code in both IE and Firefox and it seems to be working completely fine.

Test.html

```
  <html>
    <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
            <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
            <link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script>
                var postData;
                var datavalue;
                $(function(){
                    $('#tabs').tabs(
                        {
                            select: function(event, ui) {
                                datavalue = parseInt($(ui.tab).data('userid')); 
                                postData = {
                                     userid:datavalue
                                };
                            },
                            ajaxOptions: {
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: postData,
                                dataType: 'html',
                                complete: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                                    //alert(postData.userid);
                                },
                                error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                                    $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " + "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    );
                });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Intro</a></li>
                <li><a href="Department.html" data-userid="1234">Department</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>Text information goes here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Department.html:

```
             This is my department page.
```

I made changes in first two lines(variable declaration: modified postData and added one new variable to hold userid value). Modified the function assigned to "select". This seems to be working as I was able to verify the userid through an alert in "error" function of ajaxOptions.

Hope this helps. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried what you suggested, and I cant seem to get it to post, even by viewing it in Firebug. I even tried adding the url:custom/div_charts_test2.html under type, and it still wont pass that variable. Any ideas? :/

Comment: I tried validating this in Firefox(14.0.1) and iExplorer(7.0+) with a dummy page: Department.html. It seems to be working fine. I updated the above answer with my complete test code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your select function to set the ajaxOptions.

```
select:function(event, ui) {
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "ajaxOptions",{
        type: 'POST',
        data: {userId:$(ui.tab).data('userid')},
        error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
            $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " + "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
        }
    })
},
```

When you define ajaxOptions initially it uses this value for any subsequent request. But for some reason its not getting the current value. I even tried changing just the userId on select and it failed to modify it. They may be cloning the value, im not sure. Anyway if you set ajaxOptions before the request, it will send what you want.

Sorry for the half baked answer, but I couldn't let it go. +1 on the question. I had to do a little research to figure out why it wasn't working.

Note: You probably already know this, but you must be running on a server to POST. POST to the local file system will generate an error.

Comment: One more thing. Is your server setup to process the .html extension? I pointed the url in the second tab to a php file with the following content `<?php echo "<p>HELLO WORLD {$_REQUEST['userId']}</p>";` It printed 'HELLO WORLD 1234'

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {

            ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
                ui.panel.html(
                "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible."
                    );
            });

            var tabID = ui.tab[0].id;

            if (tabID == "tab1") {
                ui.ajaxSettings.url = 'ControllerName/Action/' + $('#drpDwnVal').val();
            }

            if (tabID == "tab2") {
                ui.ajaxSettings.url = 'ControllerName2/Action2/' + $('#drpDwnVal').val();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hopefully this is useful but I found a way to intercept and set the Ajax Call URL and change it based on which tab is being clicked.