# JQuery UI Ajax loaded tag cannot switch to other tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery UI tabs. Second tab is loaded dynamically based on the value of a textfield present in first tab. This is working also. But when i try to switch back to the first tab I am getting this error

> Object doesn't support this property or method

My code is here

```js
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function() {
        $(this).tabs("option", { 
            ajaxOptions: {
                cache:false,
                data: { emp_id: $('#emp_id').val() } 
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

HTML

```html
<div id="tabs" style="overflow: scroll">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Add/Remove</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Update</a></li>
        <li><a id="tab_upd" href="<%=path%>/development/hr_upd.jsp"><span>Test</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <fieldset>
            <legend style="margin-left:35%"><b><h3>HR</h3></b></legend><br/>
            <form name="hr" id="hr" method="post">
                <table border="0" align="center" width="300" bgcolor=white>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Employee ID </td>
                        <td><input type="text"  name="emp_id" id="emp_id"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                </table><br/>
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">TAB 2</div>
</div>
```

So the third tab is ajax loaded and the server side file is `hr_upd.jsp`. Everything is well the file is loaded in tab 2 with passed parameters. Only thing is I am unable to switch between tabs after the ajax tab is clicked once also.

Thanks and Regards

K guyz i did some edit, like the ajax option is implemented only when tab 2 is selected, so i gave an if condition and then i could get out of that tab(2-ajax loaded), which i couldnt before, now the new problem is, i could not get back into tab2 again.. I hope you guyz got the problem?? :). The script is below

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
        select: function(event, ui) {
       //    alert(ui.index);
           if(ui.index==2)
               {
                   $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "ajaxOptions", { data: { emp_id: $('#emp_id').val() }} );
                   return true;
               }    
        }
    });
```

Comment: use  a proper browser console to look at error. The error you are showing is a very generic IE one that doesn't provide much detail

Comment: In IE this problem normally comes if a invalid value is passed to a css style property. Since you are using IE 8 you can enable the debugging mode and enable break points to find out which line is throwing the error. Without the complete case it will be difficult for any of us to resolve this issue.

Comment: When I did debugging through ie8 debugger.. i.e from developer tools, its ahowing error at this line    "$("#tabs").tabs("option", "ajaxOptions", { 'data': { emp_id: $('#emp_id').val() } });"

Comment: K guyz so i added an if condition and i could get back from that tab to other but again I am not able to select it until the page is refreshed. the script is here  " $("#tabs").tabs({
        select: function(event, ui) {
       //    alert(ui.index);
           if(ui.index==2)
               {
                   $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "ajaxOptions", { data: { emp_id: $('#emp_id').val() }} );
                   return true;
               }    
        }
    });"

Comment: Which version of jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: its 1.9.1. My actual problem is discussed over here also "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649062/passing-variable-via-ajax-with-jquery-tabs?rq=1"   I tried the given solution, and i could not get the passed parameter, when i tried the solution from that question

Comment: Finally it is solveed! It was a jquery conflict, which i included in the called file also. Scratched ma head for so long for removing that one line, this will be helpful if some others also encouter the same prob. Thanks all