# Having Multiple "Sections/Steps" in one page - After registration mutiple SETUP steps in just one page

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm currently working on the setup page where users are being redirected to after they register/
The setup page basically make the user fill in important information and there are 3 Steps to it. I dont want to create 3 pages , one step = 1 page as i think that isnt the efficent way to go.

I did try create a new facebook account and realise that they can do it all in one page, same as other sites.

One thing i noticed is the address bar having query strings, i'm currently using codeigniter / MVC , PHP. How do i do it the "Query string(address/?step=1) etc" way that makes it changes only the form and the css ACTIVE code for tab.

Or is there any other way to get this done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating 3 views for the 3 steps and loading them via your controller through ajax.

You can have the main view in 1st step and just append view 2 and view 3 to it as user progresses.

Javascript in view1:

```
$("#next_button").click(function() {    
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?=base_url()?>controller/next_step",
        type:'POST',
        data: "step=1",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#step_form").append(data);
        },
        fail: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus );
        }
    });
});
```

Controller

```
public function next_step() {
    $step = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "step", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if($step==1) {
        echo $this->load->view("step2_view", array(), true);
    }
}
```

Though you are creating 3 views, user feels that its one page.

Comment: Can i also easily modify this onto the tab, so that when people click on the tab , it shows, LOADING... And appear again?

Comment: Yes, if you are using jQuery UI tabs (http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax), this (after little modifications) can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301193/jquery-ui-tabs-how-to-send-ajax-request-with-post-data